# C# ASP.NET: Timer - How to execute a command every quarter hour?

Tags: c#, asp.net, loops, for-loop, timer

I want to execute a command every quarter hour, on the quarter hour. (24 hour format)

so at 00:00:00, 00:15:00, 00:30:00 do something all the way up to 23:45:00

Here is a piece of code that might help you under stand what I'm talking about.

```
  protected void UpdateTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    DateStampLabel.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss");

    //CREATE FOR LOOP TO REFRESH AT EVERY QUARTER HOUR
        if (DateStampLabel.Text == "00:00:00")
        {
            Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
        }
        if (DateStampLabel.Text == "00:15:00")
        {
            Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
        }
        if (DateStampLabel.Text == "00:30:00")
        {
            Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
        }
        if (DateStampLabel.Text == "00:45:00")
        {
            Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
        }
        ...
        ...
        ...
        if (DateStampLabel.Text == "23:45:00")
        {
            Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
        }
    }
```

How can I achieve this same code with a for loop?

Comment: What do you mean "with a for loop"?  You're not looping over anything in the code.  Using a UI text element to determine the current time doesn't look very reliable, by the way.  Also, ASP.NET is absolutely not the technology to use for a recurring background task.  A Windows Service or scheduled Console Application would be more applicable.

Comment: @David's comment is incredibly useful. First off, you're using the timer tick event wrong. The `Timer` class is supposed to tick and run your event at the scheduled time interval. You shouldn't even need to use that anyway - as @David says, use a windows service or a console app with the Windows Task scheduler set to run every 15 minutes.

Comment: @Joe how is this not useful? You can't do what you want in ASP.NET - you'll hit the page and then after ~60 seconds the request will timeout and you'll never get through any part of the loop. We're telling you how to achieve what you want in a way that will actually work.

Comment: @Joe: If you insist on doing things the absolutely most wrong way possible then I'm afraid you won't find much "useful" help on Stack Overflow.  The purpose of this site is to share meaningful and helpful knowledge about software development, not to personally cater to you.

Comment: I think I found my answer. Give me some time and I'll post it.

Comment: Tip: You might not want to count on the code running at the scheduled time to the nearest second, i.e. `== "00:45:00"`. Vague timing and other tasks might cause your code to run a little late and, based on your conceptual design, it wouldn't find a match and would fall through.

Comment: dang, I solved the question but I can't answer till 8 hours after asking this question.

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < 96; i++)
            {
                TimeSpan time = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0 + (i * 900));
                string quarterHour = string.Format("{0:D2}:{1:D2}:{2:D2}", time.Hours, time.Minutes, time.Seconds);

                if (DateStampLabel.Text == quarterHour)
                {
                    Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
                }
            }

Comment: It may be somewhat simpler to calculate the current quarter-hour of the day when the timer expires: `DateTime now = DateTime.Now; int quarterHour = now.Hour * 4 + now.Minute / 15; // 0..95.`. That gives you a simple integer value, avoids fiddling about with strings, and gets you out of the "exact second" issue. Note that Windows timers only wait for _at least_ a specified period of time to elapse. They don't care about changes to the system time, DST, ... . If your application needs to account for every 0.25 of every day then you have some additional work to do.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok I figured it out. this is what I wanted to do.

```
 <script>
  function startTime() {
  document.getElementById('lblClientTime').innerHTML = moment().format('HH:mm:ss');
  var t = setTimeout(function () { startTime() }, 0);

        refresh();
    }

    function refresh() {
        //REFRESHES WEB FORM EVERY QUARTER HOUR
        for (var i = 0; i < 96; i++) {
            var startTime = moment().startOf('day').add(i * 900000).format('HH:mm:ss');

            if (lblClientTime.textContent == startTime) {
                location.reload();
            }
        }
    }
</script>
    <div id="lblClientTime" runat="server"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: I see some non-trivial issues with this solution, actually. I expanded my original answer to address them here.  :-)  http://stackoverflow.com/a/25085558/618649

Answer (score 1):

This sort of thing really cannot (and should not) be done on the server side. The only reasonable approach server-side would be to use a timer to make a callback on a background thread and manage a set of client callbacks.

I mean, you're talking about tying up not only a TCP connection but also an ASP.NET worker thread for each connected remote user for long periods of time, right? Yikes. :-)

You could use JavaScript in the browser, instead of trying so hard to tie up finite server resources:

```
window.onload = function(e){
    setInterval( function() {
        location.reload()
    }, 900000 );
}
```

**EDIT:**  The accepted answer seems to have a lot of moving parts and generate a lot of heat and smoke without real benefit. I updated my original pseudo-code to be a complete solution (above), but also demonstrate another way to do this (below), which uses a different timer API but is functionally equivalent. Basically, this takes just one line of code called from a `window.onload` event handler.

Questions I would have in a code review would include:

- Why is the HTML label decorated with runat="server" ?
- Why arbitrarily run the operation 96 times then stop?
- Why create a timer that executes immediately and only executes once, only to call a function that sits in a hot loop (ramping up CPU utilization) checking the time, when all it really does is eventually refresh the page, running the immediate-callback timer to start the hot loop over again?
- Why not just set the timer to call back after 15 minutes and refresh the page?

I have included a complete functional example just below, which reloads the page at even intervals. This would work precisely the same way with setTimeout *or* setInterval.

I set this to every couple of seconds just to demonstrate the effect. But the real point is that the page loads and once the UI is ready, sets a timer callback to a function that simply refreshes the page after the interval elapses. You don't have to sit in a hot loop checking the time, running up the CPU utilization (burning battery life, stealing CPU from other apps, etc).

Once the page finishes rendering again, the page-refresh timer callback is set again. There's really only one relevant line of code, here--the setTimeout call. The rest is just fluff to display the current timestamp when the page loads, in order to demonstrate that the refresh is working as expected.

```
<html>
    <script language="JavaScript">

        refreshInterval = 0.0333 * 60 * 1000; // minutes * seconds * ms

        window.onload = function(e){
            var now = new Date();
            var nowUI = now.getDate() + "/" + (now.getMonth()+1) + "/" + now.getFullYear() + " @ " + now.getHours() + ":"+ now.getMinutes() + ":" + now.getSeconds();

            document.getElementById('blah').innerHTML = nowUI;

            setTimeout( function(){ location.reload() }, refreshInterval );
        }

    </script>

    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div id='blah'>0</div>
    </body>
</html>
```